# Getting from an id from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I want to call a function `get` and grab 1 as some value in question controller from following url

```
http://localhost/project/index.php/question/get/1
```

The routes config I am trying is:

```
$route['question'] = 'question_controller';
$route['question/get'] = 'question_controller/get';
$route['question/(:num)'] = 'question_controller/get/$1';
```

The controller is:

```
<?php 
    /**
    * 
    */
    class Question_controller extends CI_Controller
    {

        function __construct()  
        {

            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form'));
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->helper('security');
            $this->load->model('Questions');
        }


        function get($q_id = null)
        {
            echo $q_id;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

But, the above url doesn't work at all. I am getting:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am feeling like a fool here. Also, can you please help me to remove `$route['question/get'] = 'question_controller/get';` from route field.

Comment: There is no use adding those routes like that. Just check empty or number

Comment: Regarding `get()` method those routes looks good. But I am not sure if `$route['question'] = 'question_controller';` should work since you don't have `index()` method shown there. Is your app using some redirect/rewrite  apache rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no use adding those routes like that

try this

**In Routes**

```
$route['question'] = 'question_controller';
#$route['question/get'] = 'question_controller/get'; // remove
#$route['question/(:num)'] = 'question_controller/get/$1'; // remove
```

**In Controller**

```
function get($q_id = null)
{
    if (!empty($q_id ) && is_int($q_id )) {
        echo "$q_id with the Number";
    } else {
        echo "Its Empty or Its without Number";
    }
}
```

> So when you pass `http://localhost/project/index.php/question/get/1` or `http://localhost/project/index.php/question/get` it will reach same function. It can only reach with the value or without value

Comment: not working. I tried this method too, but it didn't work. I am unable to find the controller.

Comment: http://localhost/project/index.php/question/ works fine, but http://localhost/project/index.php/question/get doesn't work. It shows me 404 error, after commenting those two lines from route page.

Comment: which code, controllers or routes? there are other routes too.

Comment: from where you calling this `ttp://localhost/project/index.php/question/` add in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115635/discussion-between-learner-and-abdulla).